# How to find the measurement of how far Tail plane to Center of gravity of the aircraft?

Tags: aerodynamics, general-aviation, avionics, measurement, private-jets

How do you find the measurement of Piper Archer Tail Plane distance to the center of the gravity.

Google really doesn't help me... maybe you guys know some website that has databases of small aircraft.

Thank you very much and best regards,

Comment: As you know the CG position varies with loads carried. The limits are explained at §2.13 of the [POH](http://www.sfcaero.com.au/pdf/PA-28-181%20Archer%20II.pdf) page 26, ([this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC32l.png) page 94 can help too)

Answer (score 1):

First you calculate the position of the CG, then you do a simple arithmetic calculation based on the station of the tailplane.